# Не отображаются картинки в List Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, adapter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При использовании кастомного адаптера в Firebase, я столкнулся с проблемой, что все работает, но не отображаются картинки в листе. Высвечивается непонятно-что, но не она. Нужно, что бы они были в нормальном листе и их можно было видеть. Я думаю это из-за контекста в Picasso. В гайде, по которому я делал, был метод wish(mContext), который я не могу использовать теперь. Пожалуйста подскажите, не понимаю, в чем причина проблемы. Придлогаю код image_item.xml
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view_upload"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

activity_images

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ImagesActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;


public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Upload> mUploads;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mContext = context;
        mUploads = uploads;
    }

    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
        Picasso.get()
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
        }
    }
}
```

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ImageAdapter mAdapter;

    private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private List<Upload> mUploads;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_images);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    mUploads.add(upload);
                }

                mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this, mUploads);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: В картинках отображается не непонятно что, а то что ты указал в пикасо - .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher). Метод get() заменил with() - это тоже ок. Ты посмотри что за url приходит, если вообще приходит что нибудь - я у тебя и текста не вижу. Проблема в получении данных с фаирбэйз.

Comment: Данные отсылаются, но прочесть я их в приложении не могу(
Как посмотреть, что за url приходит?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8UNBK06Bf4&ab_channel=CodinginFlow
Делал по этому туториалу, в комментариях закреплено сообщение, как это исправить, но оно может я что-то не так желаю((

Comment: 2022-05-06 13:22:05.735 6853-6853/com.example.help D/MyLog: Image Url: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A18711

Comment: Я про этот url - uploadCurrent.getImageUrl(), в адаптере Picasso.get()
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())

Comment: Поставил тег Log.d("MyLoggg","Image Url: " + uploadCurrent.getImageUrl());
Пишет D/MyLoggg: Image Url: null

Comment: Смотри, получается что у тебя с базы в методе onDataChange что то приходит все же, ведь судя по картинкам список mUploads не пустой (можешь проверить что mUploads.size совпадает с количеством элементов в базе). Это уже отлично. Я бы проверил что там в базе и сопоставил это с классом Upload. Можешь приложить сюда и то и другое.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. Количество элементов в базе совпадает. То что я ввожу в приложении отображается в базе четко и там и там(

Comment: https://baseindi-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/
uploads
-N1ORE1VLZv0U9GOTzNZ
-N1ORNsv_1dAmdpV7jGS
-N1OTV16t2tc_TSMjhUS
imageUrl
:
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/baseindi.appspot.com/o/uploads%2F1651842346230.jpg?alt=media&token=6cbfd7d9-8a74-4ea9-a66e-c991d68ae054"
name
:
"ккк"

Comment: Базу я не могу твою увидеть - у меня нет  прав.) Скрин бы с экрана realtime database сгодился

Comment: Изменил и добавил. Там 3 фотки и 3 имени

Comment: На вид все норм

Comment: и что теперь делать?  Может у вас есть код адаптера и листа? Я хочу научится делать кастомный адаптер

Comment: Если честно я почти не пользовался realtime database - ведь в fairbase есть еще одна база данных firestore (более молодежная и модная, вот например о ее преимуществах - https://golosay.net/firebase-cloud-firestore/). Я бы советовал пользоваться ей) А код адаптера у тебя и так вполне ничего. Лучше бы только создавать его один раз, а когда изменяется/создается список - сетать его в адаптер. И в методе onDataChange() в самом начале бы добавить mUploads.clear()

Answer (score 0):

сначала проверим ссылку на корректность,

```
Log.d("IMAGE_URL", uploadCurrent.getImageUrl());
```

если и ссылками всё ОК, замени свой пикасо на этот и проверь

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                .error(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.error_image))
                .into(holder.imageView);
```

если не получиться то замени на это

```
holder.imageView.setImageURI(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl());
```

Comment: При Log.d("IMAGE_URL", uploadCurrent.getImageUrl());
Вылит приложения 
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                .error(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.error_image))
                .into(holder.imageView);
Устаревшие пикассо( заменил, без изменений, аналогично с холдером((

Comment: А у вас метод  getImageUrl возвращает String или  URI ?  если Uri то естественно вылетит !

Comment: Нет, оно в String. holder.imageView.setImageURI(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl());
не работает( Хочет, что бы getImageUrl передввал Uri, но оно в String

Comment: В Upload.class меняй String на Uri в методе setImageUrl(String s) и в переменные imageUrl !

Comment: Я менял, везде ошибка. Log.d("IMAGE_URL", uploadCurrent.getImageUrl());
Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(), downloadUrl.toString());